# Google Sign-in always fail on GoogleSignInResult

Tags: android, google-api, google-play-services, google-plus

I need your help... I have no idea anymore !

I dont understand why it fail everytime.

- I generated the ID clients OAuth 2.0.
- I have generated and move the `google-services.json` into `./app` folder.
- By the Google Cloud Console, all Google API where activated.

Check-out and if something hurts you... Go on !

Kind regards

build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "sign.in.gogoleplusconnect"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Gogole Sign In"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>

<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
    android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package sign.in.gogoleplusconnect;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, View.OnClickListener
{
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

    private GoogleSignInOptions gso;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.d("Logger", "onCreate:");

        // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
        // profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
        gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        // Build a GoogleApiClient with access to the Google Sign-In API and the
        // options specified by gso.
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

        // Customize sign-in button. The sign-in button can be displayed in
        // multiple sizes and color schemes. It can also be contextually
        // rendered based on the requested scopes. For example. a red button may
        // be displayed when Google+ scopes are requested, but a white button
        // may be displayed when only basic profile is requested. Try adding the
        // Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN scope to the GoogleSignInOptions to see the
        // difference.
        SignInButton signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
        signInButton.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());
        signInButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        switch (v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.sign_in_button:
                Log.d("Logger", "onClick:");
                signIn();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void signIn()
    {
        Log.d("Logger", "signIn:");
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN)
        {
            Log.d("Logger", "onActivityResult:RC_SIGN_IN : " + RC_SIGN_IN);
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
    }

    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result)
    {
        Log.d("Logger", "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
        if (result.isSuccess())
        {
            Log.d("Logger", "handleSignInResult : Success");
            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

            Log.d("Logger", "" + acct.getDisplayName());
            Log.d("Logger", "" + acct.getEmail());
            Log.d("Logger", "" + acct.getPhotoUrl());
            Log.d("Logger", "" + acct.getId());
        }
        else
        {
            // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
            Log.d("Logger", "handleSignInResult : Fail");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult)
    {
        Log.d("Logger", "onConnectionFailed : Fail");
    }
}
```

Logcat.log

```
07-15 16:06:27.817 21424-21424/sign.in.gogoleplusconnect D/Logger: onCreate:
07-15 16:06:30.053 21424-21424/sign.in.gogoleplusconnect D/Logger: onClick:
07-15 16:06:30.055 21424-21424/sign.in.gogoleplusconnect D/Logger: signIn:
07-15 16:06:32.872 21424-21424/sign.in.gogoleplusconnect D/Logger: onActivityResult:RC_SIGN_IN : 9001
07-15 16:06:32.879 21424-21424/sign.in.gogoleplusconnect D/Logger: handleSignInResult:false
07-15 16:06:32.879 21424-21424/sign.in.gogoleplusconnect D/Logger: handleSignInResult : Fail
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it happened when app was signed with improper certificate, the certificate SHA-1 must be registered in Google Console.

For Debug build variant you may want to add your debug cert to Google Console as well, or configure build.gradle for debug variant to use the same certificate you registered in the console.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, replace

```
gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
```

with this:

```
gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken("web client id from console.developers.google.com for the app")
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
```

Hope this help someone. Also with firebase Signin becomes much easier. Check this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin) out.
Thanks